# Web Crypto API - Is a non-exactrable CryptoKey in IndexedDB safe enough against being passed from one device to the next?

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

The Web Crypto API offers the possibility to save a private or public key as a special, opaque type of object in the client's IndexedDB database, i.e., the client and JS runtime can work with the CryptoKey, but they cannot spell it out. Additionally, upon generation or import of said key, one can stipulate that the key be non-extractable.

My goal is to save an individual private key on a user's client device that I would use as his digital signature. It is important for me to know how hard or easy it would be to pass this CryptoKey between devices, how hard it would be for my user to give this CryptoKey to his friend or copy it to another device of his.

Comment: Future readers, regarding "The Web Crypto API offers the possibility to save a private or public key as a special, opaque type of object in the client's IndexedDB database", there are more details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#concepts-key-storage

Answer (score 4):

A key marked as non-extractable can not be exported

The WebCrypto specification is absolutely clear. See section 6 of `exportKey` [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-SubtleCrypto-method-exportKey)

> **14.3.10. The exportKey method**
>   When invoked, the exportKey method MUST perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Let format and key be the format and key parameters passed to the exportKey method, respectively.
> 2. Let promise be a new Promise.
> 3. Return promise and asynchronously perform the remaining steps.
> 4. If the following steps or referenced procedures say to throw an error, reject promise with the returned error and then terminate the algorithm.
> 5. If the name member of of the [[algorithm]] internal slot of key does not identify a registered algorithm that supports the export key operation, then throw a NotSupportedError.
> 6. **If the [[extractable]] internal slot of key is false, then throw an InvalidAccessError.**

The keying material must be hidden, even if it is stored into IndexedDB and can not be exported if the key is not extractable, so you can consider that this key can not be replicated in other device

Comment: thanks, do you know if it's just private or also public keys that can be stored in IndexedDB in a non-extractable manner?

Comment: The `extractable` attribute doesn't apply to public keys. The public key content must not be hidden so that it can be sent to a third party who needs to validate a signature or encrypt a message.

Comment: @pedrofb How do you know that someone can't open the IndexedDB database using another program, instead of a compliant user-agent? Where do you get from this definition that the keying material must be hidden, even if it's stored into IndexedDB? And if so, how is it retrieved later by the Javascript environment when the user loads a website on the right domain? Clearly the Javascript environment would have access to SOME information to access this key , retrieved from IndexedDB, for signing stuff, no?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak the keying material **must be hidden from scripts** but the way of storing the keys on the device is outside the scope of the webcrypto specification. The keys in the IndexedDb could perfectly be stored unencrypted

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to export a key in different format (However not all type of key support all format don't know why !). For this to be possible when you generate/import the key you need to specify that the key is extractable as you said. [The Web Cryptography API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-SubtleCrypto-method-exportKey) says:

> If the [[extractable]] internal slot of key is false, then throw an InvalidAccessError.

However you can export key securely (But some malicious js it your page can also extract it).

For instance if you want to be able to export a ECDSA key:

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "ECDSA",
        namedCurve: "P-256", // the curve name
    },
    true, // <== Here if you want it to be exportable !!
    ["sign", "verify"] // usage
)
.then(function(key){
    //returns a keypair object
    console.log(key);
    console.log(key.publicKey);
    console.log(key.privateKey);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Then you can export the public and private key in JWT. Example for the private key:

```
window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
    "jwk", // here you can change the format but i think that only jwk is supported for both public and private key. JWK is easier to use later
    privateKey
)
.then(function(keydata){
    //returns the exported key data
    console.log(keydata);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Then you can save it in json file and let the user download it and import it later. To add additional security you could ask for a password to encrypt the json file in AES. And forbid export once user imported the key. He/She already has it so it's useless for him to export it again.

To import the key just load the file and import the private or/and public key.

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk", 
    {
        kty: myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.kty,
        crv: myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.crv,
        x: myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.x,
        y: myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.y,
        ext: myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.ext,
    },
    {   
        name: "ECDSA",
        namedCurve: "P-256", // i think you can change it by myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.crv not sure about that
    },
    false, // <== it's useless to be able to export the key again
    myKetPubOrPrivateFromJson.key_ops
)
.then(function(publicKey){
    //returns a publicKey (or privateKey if you are importing a private key)
    console.log(publicKey);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

It's also possible to use a wrap/unwrap function however it doesn't seem to be possible to use it with ECDSA and ECDH key but here is a quick and **DIRTY** example ([live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8aycvj)):

```
function str2Buffer(data) {
  const utf8Str = decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(data));
  const len = utf8Str.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = utf8Str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return arr.buffer;
}

function buffer2Hex(buffer) {
    return Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer)).map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}

function hex2Buffer(data) {
  if (data.length % 2 === 0) {
    const bytes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
      bytes.push(parseInt(data.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return new Uint8Array(bytes).buffer;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Wrong string format');
  }
}

function createAesKey(password, salt) {
  const passwordBuf = typeof password === 'string' ? str2Buffer(password) : password;
  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        passwordBuf,
        'PBKDF2',
        false,
        ['deriveKey', 'deriveBits']
      ).then(derivedKey =>
        window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
          {
            name: 'PBKDF2',
            salt: str2Buffer(salt),
            iterations: 1000,
            hash: { name: 'SHA-512' }
          },
          derivedKey,
          {name: 'AES-CBC', length: 256},
          false,
          ['wrapKey', 'unwrapKey']
        )
     );
}

function genKeyPair() {
  return window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSA-PSS",
        modulusLength: 2048, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
        hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
    },
    true, // <== Here exportable
    ["sign", "verify"] // usage
  )
}

function exportKey(keyToWrap, wrappingKey) {
  const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
      "jwk",
      keyToWrap, //the key you want to wrap, must be able to export to above format
      wrappingKey, //the AES-CBC key with "wrapKey" usage flag
      {   //these are the wrapping key's algorithm options
          name: "AES-CBC",
          //Don't re-use initialization vectors!
          //Always generate a new iv every time your encrypt!
          iv: iv,
      }
    ).then(result => {
      const wrap = { key: buffer2Hex(result), iv: buffer2Hex(iv) };
      resolve(wrap);
    });
  });
  return promise;
}

function importKey(key, unwrappingKey, iv, usages) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
    "jwk",
    key, //the key you want to unwrap
    unwrappingKey, //the AES-CBC key with "unwrapKey" usage flag
    {   //these are the wrapping key's algorithm options
        name: "AES-CBC",
        iv: iv, //The initialization vector you used to encrypt
    },
    {   //this what you want the wrapped key to become (same as when wrapping)
        name: "RSA-PSS",
        modulusLength: 2048, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
        hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
    },
    false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    usages //the usages you want the unwrapped key to have
  );
}

createAesKey("password", "usernameassalt").then(aesKey => {
  genKeyPair().then(keyPair => {
    exportKey(keyPair.publicKey, aesKey)
      .then(publicKey => {
        exportKey(keyPair.privateKey, aesKey)
          .then(privateKey => {
            const exportKeys = {publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privateKey };
            appDiv.innerHTML = `AesKey = ${aesKey}<br />
            KeyPair:  <ul>
              <li>publicKey: ${keyPair.publicKey}</li><li>privateKey: ${keyPair.privateKey}</li>
            </ul>
            Exported: <ul>
              <li>publicKey:
                <ul>
                  <li>key: ${exportKeys.publicKey.key}</li>
                  <li>iv: ${exportKeys.publicKey.iv}</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>privateKey:
                <ul>
                  <li>key: ${exportKeys.privateKey.key}</li>
                  <li>iv: ${exportKeys.privateKey.iv}</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            <ul>`;
            importKey(hex2Buffer(exportKeys.privateKey.key), aesKey, hex2Buffer(exportKeys.privateKey.iv), ["sign"]).then(key => console.log(key)).catch(error => console.log(error.message));
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but regarding my initial question, your verdict is that a CryptoKey defined as non-extractable and stored in IndexedDB would virtually be impossible for the user to retrieve and copy to another device? This is what matters to my use case.

Comment: No non-extractable can't be exported.